# Convert TrueType glyphs to PNG image?

Tags: linux, bitmap, rendering, command-line-interface, truetype

Is there a command line tool to convert glyphs from a TTF file, to PNG (or some other bitmap image format)?

If there is no ready command line tool for that, how would you go about doing it from one of C++, Perl, Python or Ruby or something easily found on an Ubuntu box?

Comment: Good answers, but all OSX specific, even the ruby one. Thanks though! @Moose

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dump characters (glyphs) from TrueType font (TTF) into bitmaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672144/dump-characters-glyphs-from-truetype-font-ttf-into-bitmaps)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

probably partly duplicate of [How can I convert TTF glyphs to .png files on the Mac for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792189/how-can-i-convert-ttf-glyphs-to-png-files-on-the-mac-for-free)

[imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can fulfill this kind of requests, should works fine on Mac/Linux/Windows. :-)

```shell
convert -background none -fill black -font font.ttf -pointsize 300 label:"Z" z.png
```

if a batch convert is needed, maybe you can consider use a little ruby script called [ttf2png](https://github.com/yukinoraru/ttf2png) .

Answer (score 3):

## Python3

Since nobody has really address the part that specifies for C++, Python, Ruby, or Perl, here is the Python3 way. I've tried to be descriptive, but you can simplify to work how you need it to.

### Requirements: PIL (Pillow)

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)'s [ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm) and [ImageFont](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagefont.htm) module

```py
# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# use a truetype font (.ttf)
# font file from fonts.google.com (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Courier+Prime?query=courier)
font_path = "fonts/Courier Prime/"
font_name = "CourierPrime-Regular.ttf"
out_path = font_path

font_size = 16 # px
font_color = "#000000" # HEX Black

# Create Font using PIL
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path+font_name, font_size)

# Copy Desired Characters from Google Fonts Page and Paste into variable
desired_characters = "ABCČĆDĐEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠTUVWXYZŽabcčćdđefghijklmnopqrsštuvwxyzž1234567890‘?’“!”(%)[#]{@}/&\<-+÷×=>®©$€£¥¢:;,.*"

# Loop through the characters needed and save to desired location
for character in desired_characters:
    
    # Get text size of character
    width, height = font.getsize(character)
    
    # Create PNG Image with that size
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    # Draw the character
    draw.text((-2, 0), str(character), font=font, fill=font_color)
    
    # Save the character as png
    try:
        img.save(out_path + str(ord(character)) + ".png")
    except:

        print(f"[-] Couldn't Save:\t{character}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The PIL provides an [API](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagefont.htm) for this, but it's easy to use. Once you've got the PIL image, you can export it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @imcaspar, but I need it to convert icons in ttf font to png with specific sizes for ios integration

```
convert -background none -font my-icons-font.ttf -fill black  -size "240x240"  label:"0" +repage -depth 8 icon0@1x.png
```

where "0" is the character mapped for any of my icons. The extra options allowed me to have all character(icons) correctly generated as some where being cropped with regular command (+repage -depth did the job)

Answer (score 1):

For my purposes I created a shell script. Works fine on macOS if ImageMagick is installed. Not sure about other platforms.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FONT_NAME="$1"
FONT_SIZE="$2"

FILE_NAME=$(basename ${FONT_NAME} .ttf)"-${FONT_SIZE}.png"

read -r -d '' CHARSET << EOM
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789.:,;(*!?}^)#\${\%
&-+@'\"[]<>
EOM

convert -font ${FONT_NAME} -pointsize ${FONT_SIZE} label:"${CHARSET}" "${FILE_NAME}"
```

If you need additional characters exported, you might need to adjust charset variable used in script.

Call script with TTF font file and point size as arguments, as such:

`> sh ttf2png.sh alagard.ttf 20`

This script will then generate a file `alagard-20.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://sid.ethz.ch/debian/ttf2png/ttf2png-0.3.tar.gz
tar xvzf ttf2png-0.3.tar.gz
cd ttf2png-0.3 && make
./ttf2png ttf2png -l 11 -s 18 -e -o test.png /path/to/your/font.ttf
eog test.png&
```