# Determining height and length of text in pixels given the font

Tags: html, python-3.x

This is mostly an HTML question, but I am interested in extracting information from the HTML using Python 3.

---

My question is:

> Given a font-family, font-weight, and font-style, as well as the text itself and the text-size, how can I determine the height and width of the text?

Namely, I have the coordinates of the upper left corner of the text, and I would like to find its lower right corner. I am ready to manually input the sizes of single letters in my script, if that's what it takes (hopefully not!).

---

As a base example, I have a font

```
f { font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; }
```

and a tag

```
<span id="f" style="font-size:20px;vertical-align:baseline;color:rgba(0,0,0,1);">Hello, world!</span>
```

I would like to calculate the width and height of the text, in pixels.

---

I am aware of related questions on the site, but I couldn't find any that would answer my specific question. Feel free to link such a question (if answered), if it exists.

Comment: You can just calculate the size of the span, right?

Comment: Would you be able to use selenium, like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python

Comment: @BramVanroy How would I go about it? I am not far from an expert when it comes to HTML...

Comment: @GammaGames I am not sure. I will look into it. Alternative solutions are appreciated, but thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround solution to this (not implemented yet). The parsing of the fonts is (often) done through referral to a .ttf (TrueFont) file. You can find such files in `C:/Windows/Fonts` (in Windows, not sure about other OS).

Using PIL/Pillow in Python, you can draw the bitmap of any string in a given font, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672182/2312835). To be exact, you want to use `PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getmask` after initialising an instance of `ImageFont` with the appropriate .ttf file. Then you can just get the size of the mask and rescale to match the font size.